# Need assistance converting datetimeoffset in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I'm working on a data migration from SQL Server 2019 to PostgreSQL 14. Some of our data is stored in `datetimeoffset` columns, and due to different precisions between the two platforms, I'm unable to validate the data.

Specifically, the precision in SQL Server is to 0.1 microseconds, while in PostgreSQL it's to 0.1 milliseconds, rounded up as appropriate. I'm not concerned about the loss of precision, but comparisons between the two inevitably fail. Here is an example:

SQL Server: `2022-06-06 10:31:13.1707995 -05:00`

PostgreSQL: `2022-06-06 10:31:13.1708 -05:00`

Is there a way I can convert the value in SQL Server to the PostgreSQL value using existing SQL Server functions? Or convert both to a different, third value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> SQL Server: 2022-06-06 10:31:13.1707995 -05:00
>
> PostgreSQL: 2022-06-06 10:31:13.1708 -05:00
>
> Is there a way I can convert the value in SQL Server to the PostgreSQL
> value using existing SQL Server functions

You can use a T-SQL CAST of the datetimeoffset column to the desired precision and the source value will be rounded accordingly:

```
SELECT CAST('2022-06-06T10:31:13.1707995-05:00' AS datetimeoffset(4));
```

Yields `2022-06-06 10:31:13.1708 -05:00`